# Water heater not producing hot water but everything seems to be working?

Tags: electrical, thermostat, heating, water-heater

We just bought a house and the previous owner had a brand new water heater installed. The first day we took a shower it was not very warm and the next day there was no hot water at all.

I checked the breaker and found the breaker had been tripped. After resetting the breaker we noticed the hot water was still not working so I checked the breaker again and it seemed fine.

Next I got a multimeter and check both the top and bottom thermostats and those appear to be getting 228-230 volts to them (I thought they should be getting 240 so this might be a problem).

When I check the top element it was getting the same voltage as the top thermostat.

The bottom element was not getting power but from what I have read only one element can be on at a time. I did try to turn the top to 120 degrees and the bottom to 150 degrees to force it to switch what element was getting power but nothing changed.

Then I turned off the power and removed all the wires from both elements and tested their ohms. They both fell within expected resistance: the top was about 15 ohms and the bottom about 12.

Still we have no hot water and the inner wall of the tank is not warm to the touch so I know the water inside is not hot so it's very odd.

The model is a AO Smith E6-50H45DV 120.

I have also pressed that red reset button every time I turned the power back on but it does not seem to be helping either.

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: "*We just bought a house and the previous owner had a brand new water heater installed*" Is it under warranty ?

Comment: @AlaskaMan well thats the next step but the previous owners have not really given us much in the way of warranty info and a home warranty call out is $75 so I was trying to figure it out on my own before resorting to calling someone.

Comment: Have you tested the voltage across the element connections? Electric water heaters are dead stupid simple.   It's either a thermostat or an element (which you probably eliminated as a cause).  But if you have power across the element, I don't care what your ohm-meter said, it's a bad element. If you don't have power it's a bad t-stat. Normally the bottom element comes on first, then, if there is a high demand for HW, the upper element cuts off the lower one and turns on.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Well I did say in my question that I tested power to both the t-stat and the element. The top t-stat and element are getting 227v right now. The bottom I am not sure as i can only figure out how to test the bottom element but I was not 100% sure about the bottom thermostat. But if the top is getting power and the elements are good then it should be at least heating from the top. Also everything I read said that testing the ohm is how you check if its a bad element so how else would I know?

Comment: `top t-stat and element are getting 227v right now` that does not mean that the element or the thermostat are ok ... you would read that voltage if nothing was connected ... a thermostat that has contacts closed (connected) should read near zero volts across the contacts ... so, if you measure voltage across thermostat contacts, then that thermostat is not conducting current

Comment: have you checked out AO Smith's technical training/support literature and online resources here: https://university.hotwater.com/products/residential/standard-electric/